# concatenate vectors if cycle matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, concatenation

```
distances = sqrt((x - max(x)).^2 + (y - max(y)).^2);
    [peaks, iPeaks] = findpeaks(distances);%to find out where the curve turns around
          for i = 1 : length(iPeaks)-1
                    iPeaks1 = iPeaks(i);
                    iPeaks2 = iPeaks(i+1)-1;%analyse of consecutive pair of peaks
                     %skip small noise peaks
                   if length(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)>=5 
                      xx=x(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)
                       yy=y(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)
                   end
                end
```

hello

i need to construct vectors xx and yy. The problem is that at each cycle the past xx and yy is deleted but i want the opposite. i want them to keep the past information and grow at each cycle. what can i do? and also i know i should preallocate xx and yy.

i appreciate any help. thank you very much.

****this is a possible solution. the problem here is i need to preallocate. but if i do it, the xx and yy keep the zeros and continue to grow 'with the zeros inside' and that is wrong

:

```
distances = sqrt((x - max(x)).^2 + (y - max(y)).^2);
[peaks, iPeaks] = findpeaks(distances);%to find out where the curve turns around
xx=[];
yy=[];
for i = 1 : length(iPeaks)-1
        iPeaks1 = iPeaks(i);
        iPeaks2 = iPeaks(i+1)-1;%analyse of consecutive pair of peaks
         %skip small noise peaks
       if length(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)>=5 
          xx = [xx; x(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)];%''concatenate''(connect)
          yy = [yy; y(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)];
       end
end
```

Comment: I think you confuse things. You do not preallocate `xx` and `yy`. You initialize them to empty. Whatever you then append to them is your data, not some un-needed zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Growing a vector is easily done using concatenation:

```
x = [1, 2, 3];
y = [4, 5, 6, 7];
z = [x, y]; %# z will be [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

In your case you would do

```
%# Start with an empty vector.
xx = [];
for i = 1 : length(iPeaksNoise)-1
    [...]
    xx = [xx, x(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)];
end
```

To be independent of the shape of `iPeaksNoise` (i.e. no matter if it is a row- or
column-vector) you could use

```
for [...]
    t = x(iPeaks1:iPeaks2);
    xx = [xx; t(:)];
end
```

Preallocation means to create a vector of zeros, which has the length of your **final** output. You would do something like this

```
final_size = what_so_ever;
xx = zeros(final_size, 1);
start_index = 1;
for [...]
    t = x(iPeaks1:iPeaks2);
    xx(start_index : start_index + length(t) - 1) = t;
    start_index = start_index + length(t);
end
```

However, in your case you have the additional difficulty that do not know the final size 
of `xx` in advance, because you do not know how often `length(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)>=5` is 
fulfilled inside the loop.

**Edit:**

A code with pre-allocation of `xx` could look like:

```
distances = sqrt((x - max(x)).^2 + (y - max(y)).^2);
[peaks, iPeaks] = findpeaks(distances);

%# Compute the distance between two peaks.
peakDistance = diff(iPeaks);
%# Filter peaks which are of length 5 or less.
peakMask = peakDistance > 5;
finalSize = sum(peakDistance(peakMask));
%# Copy the values in a new vector.
xx = zeros(1, finalSize);
idx = 1;
for count = 1 : length(peakDistance)
  if peakMask(count)
    pD = peakDistance(count);
    xx(idx : idx + pD - 1) = x(iPeaks(count) : iPeaks(count) + pD - 1);
    idx = idx + pD;
  end
end
```

Comment: well, yes, and that is of the problems. can you please see the new code i wrote in the 'question space'. do you know what i could do to solve the problem? thank you so much.

Comment: @user1675777: I added an example with pre-allocation based on your edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly state where in `xx` and `yy` you want to place the data. From your code it is difficult to understand where you want it, but it should look something in these lines

```
start = some_index_in_xx;
v = x(iPeaks1:iPeaks2);
xx(start:start+numel(v)-1)=v;
```

And the same for `yy`. `start` you have to compute yourself.

If on the other hand you want to append the new `x` and `y` vector parts to the end of `xx` and `yy`, you'd do this

```
xx = [xx x(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)];
yy = [yy y(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)];
```

You have to initialize `xx` and `yy` before the loop:

```
xx = [];
yy = [];
```

Comment: i am sorry, what do you mean with 'start = some_index_in_xx'? i want to fill in xx from the beginning, so 1? i changed the question and plotted the all code. maybe it is easier for you to help me. thank you so so much.

Comment: If you have preallocated xx, it has an initial size (e.g. `xx=zeros(1,1000)`. Your vector `v` is, say, 10 elements. Where do you want to put it in `xx`? starting from which index?

Comment: can you please see the solution i wrote in the question space? do you have any idea of what i could do to solve it? thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm presuming that the number of elements you are going to add to xx and yy in each iteration is NOT the same every time. Then if you want to preallocate space you need to find out how much you are going to add up then. So the code will become more complicated with an extra loop. One version might be

```
x=(5*sin(0:(pi/100):2*pi)+rand(201,1)'-0.5)';
y=(5*cos(0:(pi/100):2*pi)+rand(201,1)'-0.5)';
%%
distances = sqrt((x - max(x)).^2 + (y - max(y)).^2);
[peaks, iPeaks] = findpeaks(distances);%to find out where the curve turns around

counterx = 0;
for i = 1 : length(iPeaks)-1
    iPeaks1 = iPeaks(i);
    iPeaks2 = iPeaks(i+1)-1;%analyse of consecutive pair of peaks
    %skip small noise peaks
    if length(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)>=5
        counterx =counterx+ iPeaks2-iPeaks1+1;
    end
end
xx=zeros(counterx,1);
yy=xx;
counterx=0;
clc
for i = 1 : length(iPeaks)-1
    iPeaks1 = iPeaks(i);
    iPeaks2 = iPeaks(i+1)-1;%analyse of consecutive pair of peaks
    %skip small noise peaks
    if length(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)>=5
        %         xx = [xx; x(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)];%''concatenate''(connect)
        %         yy = [yy; y(iPeaks1:iPeaks2)];
        counterx=counterx+1;
        xx(counterx:counterx+iPeaks2-iPeaks1) = x(iPeaks1:iPeaks2);
        yy(counterx:counterx+iPeaks2-iPeaks1) = y(iPeaks1:iPeaks2);
        counterx=counterx+iPeaks2-iPeaks1;
    end
end
disp([xx yy]')
```

But then, this is matlab. You shouldn't have to do all that. Here's some code that does the same thing using logical flags and just removes all the small peaks in a single swoop:

```
% find all the iPeaks that are 5 apart from the next one
peakdiffs = find((iPeaks(2:end)-iPeaks(1:end-1)-1)>=5);
% make a logical array quickly with same size as x
removeflag = x<=inf;
for i=1:numel(peakdiffs)
    % for each peak that is bigger than your threshold, those parts of the
    % logical array will be made false.
    removeflag(iPeaks(peakdiffs(i)):iPeaks(peakdiffs(i)+1)-1)=false;
end
%remove all indices in x,y that are still false in removeflag and store in xx
%and yy resp
xx= x; xx(removeflag)=[];
yy= x; yy(removeflag)=[];
disp([xx yy]')
```